# How to insert data in column that reference an object

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

Below is my code

```sql
create or REPLACE type obj2 is object(e1 varchar2(20), e2 varchar2(20));
/
create table tbl2 (col1 varchar2(20), col2 ref obj2);
insert into tbl2 values('aa',obj2('aa','aa'));
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF OBJ2 got OBJ2
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can insert be done only through PL/SQL or am I doing this in the wrong way?

Comment: @Abra That would create a copy of the object in the column. If you then create two rows in `tbl2` with the same values then you will have 2 identical copies of the object that are independent. If you use a `REF`erence then you can have one instance of the object (stored in an object-derived table) and both references point at the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `REF`erence column needs to reference an object stored in an object-derived table.

```sql
CREATE TYPE obj2 IS OBJECT(e1 varchar2(20), e2 varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE obj2_table OF obj2;

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
  col1 varchar2(20),
  col2 REF obj2 SCOPE IS obj2_table
);

INSERT INTO obj2_table (e1, e2) VALUES ('aa','aa');

INSERT INTO tbl2 (
  col1,
  col2
) VALUES (
  'aa',
  (SELECT REF(o) FrOM obj2_table o WHERE e1 = 'aa' AND e2 = 'aa')
);

DECLARE
  v_ref REF obj2;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO obj2_table t VALUES (obj2('b','bb')) RETURNING REF(t) INTO v_ref;

  INSERT INTO tbl2 (col1, col2) VALUES ('bbb', v_ref);
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT t.col1,
       t.col2.e1,
       t.col2.e2
FROM   tbl2 t
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2.E1 | COL2.E2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | aa | aa |
| bbb | b | bb |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nUka6TLg)

Comment: So object type cannot be referenced directly . we need to create a table "obj2_table " first and then create another table "TBL2"  which REF the first table. Is my understanding correct

Comment: @Erik A `REF`erence is to an object stored as a row in an object-derived table. You need to create the object and then create the object-derived table using `CREATE TABLE ... OF ...` and then you can put the object into the table and reference it. You cannot reference an object that is not stored anywhere (and just exists in memory); you need to actually have a place for the reference to point at.

Comment: OK Understood now :)